# sonarqube | Wrapper Stopped | 7.1

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting below error in sonar.log. I have installed Sonarqube 7.1 version in AWS Other Linux OS. Java -version is openjdk version "1.8.0_201". And nginx.repo configuration is:-

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/7/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Error logs:- sonar.log

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2019.09.27 13:13:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/efs/sonar/temp
2019.09.27 13:13:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.09.27 13:13:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/efs/sonar/elasticsearch]: /opt/efs/sonar/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/efs/sonar/temp/conf/es
2019.09.27 13:13:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2019.09.27 13:13:27 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.09.27 13:13:27 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.09.27 13:13:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2019.09.27 13:13:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/efs/sonar]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.amzn2.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/efs/sonar/temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*:/opt/efs/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/efs/sonar/temp/sq-process3612618067556786670properties
Fri Sep 27 13:13:55 UTC 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Sep 27 13:13:56 UTC 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2019.09.27 13:13:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2019.09.27 13:13:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2019.09.27 13:13:59 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
2019.09.27 13:13:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Adding wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dsonar.wrapped=true
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/jsw/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../lib/common/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../../lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
wrapper.java.initmemory=8
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32
wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile=../../logs/sonar.log
wrapper.logfile.format=M
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE
wrapper.console.title=SonarQube  
wrapper.single_invocation=true
wrapper.ntservice.name=SonarQube
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=SonarQube
wrapper.ntservice.description=SonarQube
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
wrapper.disable_restarts=TRUE
wrapper.ping.timeout=0
wrapper.shutdown.timeout=300
wrapper.jvm_exit.timeout=300
```

List of plugins installed until now under /opt/efs/sonar/extension/plugins folder:-

```
sonar-apigee-plugin-2.0.0.jar
sonar-auth-bitbucket-plugin-1.0.jar
sonar-csharp-plugin-7.0.1.4822.jar
sonar-flex-plugin-2.4.0.1222.jar
sonar-java-plugin-5.2.0.13398.jar
sonar-javascript-plugin-4.1.0.6085.jar
sonar-php-plugin-2.13.0.3107.jar
sonar-python-plugin-1.9.1.2080.jar
sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.4.0.1037.jar
sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.7.0.1017.jar
sonar-typescript-plugin-1.6.0.2388.jar
sonar-xml-plugin-2.0.1.2020.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

After giving 644 permission to *.jar plugin it started working